# publish python package include sub directories

Tags: python, pypi

I am trying to upload python package to PyPi and Anaconda. here's the tree structure of my project `example`:

```
.
├── LICENSE
├── MINIFEST.in
├── README.md
├── setup.py
└── example
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── algorithms
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── calculations
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── common.py
    │   │   └── discrete.py
    │   ├── regression
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── bezier.py
    │   │   ├── constants.py
    │   │   ├── describe.py
    │   │   ├── funcs.py
    │   │   ├── matrices.py
    │   │   ├── modules.py
    │   │   ├── mono.py
    │   │   └── regress.py
    │   └── sketch
    │       ├── __init__.py
    │       ├── data.py
    │       ├── outliers.py
    │       ├── settings.py
    │       └── theme.py
    └── main.py
```

`setup.py` follows by

```py
from setuptools import setup


def readme():
    with open('README.md') as f:
        info = f.read()
    return info


setup(
    name='example',
    version='1.0.0',
    description='example desc',
    long_description=readme(),
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    url='https://github.com/test/test',
    author='test',
    author_email='test@gmail.com',
    license='MIT',
    classifiers=[
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8",
    ],
    packages=['example'],
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[],
)
```

however, after publication, I used `pip install`, and the directory I got is:

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   └── main.cpython-37.pyc
└── main.py
```

---

I have read

- [How to include package sub-folders in my project distribution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650331/how-to-include-package-sub-folders-in-my-project-distribution)

but mine are python files instead of static javascript.

---

I have read [Subfolder in Python package not visible when installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68047686/subfolder-in-python-package-not-visible-when-installed)

and changed my `setup.py` to:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages


def readme():
    with open('README.md') as f:
        info = f.read()
    return info


setup(
    name='example',
    version='1.0.1',
    description='example desc',
    long_description=readme(),
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    url='https://github.com/test/test/',
    author='example',
    author_email='example@gmail.com',
    license='MIT',
    classifiers=[
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8",
    ],
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[],
)
```

after publication, I installed my package by pip install, but this time, all my files are there, which the tree looks exactly as what I expected. however, in `main.py`,

```py
from algorithms.sketch.data import *
# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'algorithms'
```

---

Then I tried [Why do I need to include sub-packages in setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50083553/why-do-i-need-to-include-sub-packages-in-setup-py)

which `setup.py`

```py
from setuptools import setup


def readme():
    with open('README.md') as f:
        info = f.read()
    return info


setup(
    name='example',
    version='1.0.3',
    description='example',
    long_description=readme(),
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    url='https://github.com/example/example/',
    author='example',
    author_email='example@gmail.com',
    license='MIT',
    classifiers=[
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8",
    ],
    packages=['example', 'example.algorithms', 'example.algorithms.calculations', 'example.algorithms.regression', 'example.algorithms.sketch'],
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[],
)
```

exactly like before:

- all my directories are there
- if I run `main.py` explicitly in `side_packages`, it works fine.
- but if I use it as a package, which `from example.main import *`, and it results the same error as above

```py
from algorithms.sketch.data import *
# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'algorithms'
```

---

MAINIFEST.in follows by:

```
include README.md LICENSE
```

---

any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: What you have created is actually a namespace package called `example.algorithms` when you used `packages=find_packages()` as is.  You will need to `from example.algorithms.sketch.data import *`. If you want `example/` to be the "root" of the project (even though typically it would be called `src/`), You will need `packages=find_packages('example')` and `package_dir={'': 'example'},` passed to `setup()`.

Comment: If you want to do relative imports instead, e.g. if the module is inside `example/`, importing the relative `algorithms` subpackage will need to be done using `import .algorithms...`